# How to use dask for function with no return ? (image processing)

Tags: python, image-processing, dask-delayed

I have a function `crop_images_circle(file_dir,kmeans_dir,folders_dir,filename)`. that does not return any thing.
Trying to use dask to parallalise the computation.

Implementation without dask for some 100 odd files:

```
for filename in os.listdir(file_dir):
    crop_images_circle(file_dir,kmeans_dir,folders_dir,filename)
```

Execution time in seconds: 53.58223843574524

Implementation with dask :

```
# Version 1
for filename in os.listdir(file_dir):
    x = delayed(crop_images_circle)(file_dir,kmeans_dir,folders_dir,filename)
    x.compute()
```

Execution time in seconds: 46.36917209625244

```
# Version 2
for filename in os.listdir(file_dir):
    x = delayed(crop_images_circle)(file_dir,kmeans_dir,folders_dir,filename)

x.compute()
```

Version 2 of dask just process one Image. Not sure why. Documentation does mention similar use,
TIme required is not that significantly different. Is there a improvement using a dask ? Or I am messing up the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

###### This is from dask best practices. might answer the quesion above

---

## Don’t rely on side effects

> Delayed functions only do something if they are computed. You will
> always need to pass the output to something that eventually calls
> compute.
>
> [image]